# Retrieving calling context in a BroadcastReceiver()

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am trying to show a alert dialog fragment from a broadcast receiver but the receiver is not in the activity that will be showing the fragment (the receiver handles all errors broadcast on this event, regardless of whether it is active activity or not).

Here is my current receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mHttpPostReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
              if (intent.getStringExtra("Error") != null) { // error occurred
                      // called from a fragment in another activity
                      NetworkError.show(((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), error);
               }
      }
};
```

But the context parameter in the function is the current context of the activity it is in and causes runtime illegal state exceptions since this activity isn't on the screen. Is there any way to send the calling function's context like through the broadcast? Or is there another way I should be implementing this?

The specific error I am currently getting is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add extras that say the calling `Activity` from the `Intent` that you are bcroadcasting, then based on that, writes to something like `SharedPreferences`. Then in the Activity's `onResume()`, you check to see if the preferences' key contains a message, and updates the UI then.

Eg

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
  if (intent.getStringExtra("Error") != null) { 
    String callingActivity = intent.getStringExtra ("CallingActivity");
    if (callingActivity != null);
    context.getSharedPreferences (callingActivity, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString ("errorMessage", "You have an error").commit();
  }
}
```

Then in each Activity's `onResume()`

```
@Override
 protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  String errorMsg =context.getSharedPreferences ("ThisActivityName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString ("error");
  if (errorMsg.equals ("You have an error")){
    //update fragment code here.  
    //set SharedPreference errorMessage key to hold something else.
  } 
}
```

The way I have it, each Activity has its own SharedPreferences database, with the database name the same name as `callingActivity`. This means when you read in from onResume(), `"ThisActivityName"` should be the same string as `callingActivity`. But this is the main idea, you can modify this.

Comment: this would work but the activity calling this one isn't paused. The calling activity sends the broadcast then idles, the method above now creates a SharedPreferences entry but the calling function does not reach the onResume method afterwards.

Comment: @user1988523 what do you mean by *idles*? Do you mean that the Activity's `onPause()` is not being called?

Comment: That seems to be the case. I set breakpoints in the onPause() and onResume() of the calling function but they are never reached. During this time, the calling fragment creates a thread which sends the broadcast which is then received by the function above in another activity (the original fragment does nothing after the broadcast is sent).

Comment: @user1988523 I don't see why the Activity wouldn't pause, but Fragments also have `onPause()/Resume()`, you can try this approach.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but this wasn't a high priority issue in the project. Your answer works but since the onPause() was never called until the screen went black, I instead created broadcast-receivers for error-handling that required dialogs in every activity and using the SharedPreferences to determine activity "visibility" determined which activity should handle the error. Thanks for the insight. Since this application uses mostly fragments and few activities this is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this inside onReceive method:

```
    if (context instanceof LoginActivity) {
        switchLoginFields((LoginActivity) context, isConnected);
    } else if (context instanceof ReceiptActivity || context instanceof AmountActivity) {
        showArelt(context, isConnected);
    }
```

Comment: I need to use the broadcast sender's context, not the context in the function above (although this would be useful once I have that).